# Change each letter on input string C#

Tags: c#, windows, encryption

I want to create an application con C# where every letter in a string changes it's value.

For example:

```
Input string: Hello world.
```

And according with this:

```
h = f, 
e = 3, 
l = 1, 
l = 1, 
o = 0, 
blank space = x, 

w = s, 
o = 0, 
r = 5, 
l = 1, 
d = g.

So the output should be: f3110xs051g
```

The main idea is: How can I change every letter in a string, trying to simulate an encryption? I've tried with a string.Replace() within a "for" loop but it returns the same text. How can I change it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please post the code you have so far.

Comment: What have you tried? You need to show us your code so we can help you. Here's a hint: what you're trying to do is something called a *substitution cipher*. A little Google-fu will go a long way towards a solution. Another hint: C# strings are **immutable** (they can't be changed). You might try reading a good book on C#.

Comment: Create a map (for example `HashSet`) and add every symbol-to-symbol conversion as a key-value pair. Afterwards loop over every character in your string, look it up in the set and replace it with the appropriate value. I'm not going to write the code for you since you have shown no effort.

Comment: You probably know this, but just to be safe, I'll post it (as much for future readers). You say you want to use it to *simulate* encryption. I hope that's what you mean - just as a simulation, and not as real encryption... since this type of thing is trivial to decode (even by hand).

Answer (score 2):

You can try creating a string, string dictionary and load it with the mapping you need. Then create a char array and apply a lambda that will transform the string values and finally join the result.

```
Dictionary<char,char> d = new Dictionary<char,char>();
d.Add('h','f'); 
d.Add('e','3');
d.Add('l','1');
d.Add('o','0');
d.Add(' ','x');

String.Concat("hello".Select (x => d[x]));
```

But i think you should use an encryption library.

Comment: 1) you just want a `Dictionary<char, char>` instead.  It'll make everything simpler.  2) `ToCharArray` is unneeded; `string` implements `IEnumerable<char>` 3) You should just use `String.Concat` rather than `String.Join` since you're concatting the strings, semantically, not joining them.

Comment: @Servy +1 for a very constructive comment. I will apply your notes with your permission...

Comment: That's why I made them.

Comment: @Servy The only thing i seem to fail to change is the ToCharArray(). I don't get an option of .Select in the "hello". Am i missing something?

Comment: @Servy Well, though i didn't get the option on LINQPad, i tried it anyway, and it worked...

Comment: I do it all the time; no idea why it wouldn't be working for you.

Answer (score -2):

String.Replace() returns a string, and doesn't modify the original object.

You need to set your string to the return value of the replace function:

```
String test = "abcdefg";
test = test.Replace("abc", "xyz");
```

Comment: I've tried this too, but I want to change every letter not just a phrase or 1 letter. :(

Comment: No need to downvote me, I'm simply trying to project why you might still be getting your original value with your replace functions. It's hard to give exact advice if you don't supply any code to work with.

Comment: I didn't downvote you. Sorry if anyone else did it. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score -2):

First of all next time show the actual code you tried

Second of all `String.Replace()` don't replace the string, it returns the replaced string so you want this :

```
text = text.Replace("h","f")
```

Third of all, you don't need to loop, `String.Replace()` replace all the instance of the old value

Fourth and last, read the [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx)

Comment: Whoops, my fault. This is my first time at Stackoverflow I won't miss the code next time.

Comment: @Panacek Meh no problem, remember that people are expecting for OPs to show that they have made some efforts before asking, as for the `String.Replace` it's probably not so much of the best option, there are a gazillion options for string manipulation in C# look around a bit, you'll find good alternative by yourself

Comment: `Replace` is incapable of solving this problem.  If you map all of the `h`'s to `f`'s, then map all of the `f`'s to `e`'s (or whatever) you don't know which of the `f`'s where there in the original and which are mapped `h`'s.